# How do you filter in SQL by a dynamic number of date ranges?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Let's say I have these tables.

```
Users

| id | name |
|----|------|
| 1  | bob  |
```

```
Posts

| id | title         | created_at                 | user_id |
|----|---------------|----------------------------|---------|
| 1  | hello world   | 2020-05-15 18:29:13.163687 | 1       |
| 2  | hello world 2 | 2020-06-15 18:29:13.163687 | 1       |
| 3  | hello world 3 | 2020-07-15 18:29:13.163687 | 1       |
```

```
Snoozes

| id | start_at                   | end_at                     | user_id |
|----|----------------------------|----------------------------|---------|
| 1  | 2020-05-01 18:29:13.163687 | 2020-05-30 18:29:13.163687 | 1       |
| 2  | 2020-06-01 18:29:13.163687 | 2020-06-30 18:29:13.163687 | 1       |
| 3  | 2020-07-01 18:29:13.163687 | 2020-07-13 18:29:13.163687 | 1       |
```

For each user, I want to get the posts that they created when they were not in snooze mode. The number of snooze mode instances they have will vary.

If done correctly with the example data, the only post I'd get back is post id 3.

Comment: Did you try with WHERE NOT EXISTS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select p.*
from posts p
where not exists (select 1
                  from snoozes s
                  where p.user_id = s.user_id and
                        p.created_at between s.start_at and s.end_at
                 );
```